# Transparency doesn't work (Cycles)

Tags: transparency

I tried to Render my Picture with a transparent background.
Without transparent background it works fine, but with there's just an empty transparency. I checked my compositing Nodes and I checked ''Use Alpha'' everywhere.
Here's the file and I hope somebody can find the problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/yb20indgoo0ytj43zn4en/Karate%20Feuer%202.blend1?dl=0&oref=wn&r=AAkBychaZdNTj3mYiYbUNkL9HH9-5nvpqg0_Cmf24Mn0vanH9M79oGJ2w5Z6yg7HARZE_EcBsMs7KazCatDo0pLNnv3P7foaKPJ9drS8jFu0HMNV_nxAtRB2yp5CkkDvNPN6nRQQwx_jrxoFemGBYfMSJo52FGKeblcS-2atpeG2YvtgangWrXPY66aKa7phi8U&sm=1

Comment: Please use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend files. Also, while it can be good to have a blend file to look at, we would ideally be able to solve the problem without having to download a file, by having a well described question with pictures.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add make an effort to describe in your question what kind of scene you are dealing with. Add images that show your scene  and settings. And read [What is the problem with only posting a link and asking “How do I do this?”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this)

Answer (score 0):

The setting you want is in the render layers tab:

[image]

Unchecking this box will give you a transparent background instead of rendering the sky/environment map.